# Switching between security plugins is a risk?

Tags: security

For years I used the same plugin to secure my clients websites.

The plugin helps me keeping my websites secure by changing the login URL, by setting a captcha question, disabling file editing etc etc.

What I realised is that this plugin is not supported and updated like others competitors. For this reason I decided to switch plugin on all my sites.

My question is now: is possible that when switching from plugin to plugin some files from the old one remains and creates conflicts (and security issues) with the new plugin?

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

First thing is: a good plugin should always remove its trace when uninstalled completely.

Any changes, whether plugin install, enabling new feature etc. **should not be done** on live server. We developers always do tests on a local server. And a good one for anybody could be [Local by Flywheel](https://local.getflywheel.com/).

If you are desperate to test things on live server, *always*, I repeat *always*, have a solid, tested backup before proceeding. Because you don't know [until thorough code-reading] how the plugin/theme is coded.

Now let's answer your question:

> *is possible that when switching from plugin to plugin some files from the old one remains and creates conflicts (and security issues) with the new plugin?*

*If and only if* your active plugin is a good one, it will remove its trace on uninstallation. And thus it'll clear its traces while removed.

*Then and only then* you can assure yourself that, you can have a clean install of a new plugin without conflict.

But typically popular plugins conflict less than other. So you can have a try, after having a strong backup.

> *Switching between security plugins is a risk?*

And switching security plugins is never a risk because both are doing their job to secure you, if they really did what they really are saying. If you are curious about plugins' traces, have a good read on this thread:

> [**Disabled plugins are they security holes - rumor or reality?** — WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/125483/22728)

And the bottom line is: ***Is your plugin coded good enough to trust it?***

### Update

And I'd love to recommend Ipstenu's article about security through obscurity:

- [**Still Not Using Plugins for Security**](https://halfelf.org/2018/still-not-using-plugins-for-security/) - *Mika Ariela Epstein*